# Converting String object to Date object

Tags: java

Hi i am truing to convert this string `2015-11-26` to `Date` object so:

I am trying this:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date result=null;  
    try {
        result = df.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(XmlReaderDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    codecurrency.setDate(result);
```

And `date` is the string holding `2015-11-26`

It gives me exception and I don't know why.

Comment: What kind of exception?

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Comment: And date is the string holding 2015-11-26 It gives me exception and i dnt know why. If any ideas please help me.

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: SEVERE: null
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Exhange rates" thats all it gives me

Comment: looks like the `date` variable doesn't hold what you think. Try insert `System.out.println(date);` before `result = df.parse(date);` and see what it outputs.

Comment: did you check how I suggested?

Comment: if yes, that means the error is in `codecurrency.setDate(result)` line, so please post its source code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
public class DateExample {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        String date = "2015-11-26";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date result = null;  
        try {
            result = df.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
    }
}
```

I just changed it a bit, so it compiles.

If you still can't get it to work, please post a [Runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can provide more and better help.

This is the output I get:

```
result: Thu Nov 26 00:00:00 CST 2015
```

Also looking at the exception and your code, you probably want to move this line:

```
codecurrency.setDate(result);
```

inside the `try` call...